# monitor ram bandwidth real time on android

Tags: android, ram, monitor

recently, I'm trying to find out a way to monitor the ram bandwidth real time on android smartphone, I've tried to use top command, but it only shows how many percentage of ram have been occupied, it doesn't show any bandwidth information, do you guys have any idea how to do that? thanks a lot.

Comment: bandwidth is fixed number capability thing which does not depend on time. I assume you want to gets some statistics about total number of bytes going between CPU and RAM at any given moment. In case of network / disk I/O data goes through software drivers which can keep numbers which can be used to calculate the load of channel. But in case of CPU->RAM there is no software sits between them so you can't get such numbers in a similar way. Probably you could get some stats from memory controller but it would be quite low level thing and highly hardware specific.

Comment: hi Maxim, yes, i do need to monitor data traffic between cpu and dram, seems I need to work on low level.....